# sleep function not working in php

Tags: php

i am trying to send many mails at time with some time interval and this is my code.

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['init']) && isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && isset($_GET['company']) && $_GET['company'] != '') {
    require_once("../../includes/config.php");
    $failed = 0; $success = 0; $values = '';
    require_once('../../includes/mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $companyResult = mysql_query("SELECT com_name,com_email,password,com_id FROM company_details WHERE com_id IN (".$_GET['company'].")");
    $n = 0; $s = 0;
    while ($companyRow = mysql_fetch_array($companyResult)) {
        $mailBody = "Hello There '".date('h:i:s')."'";
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'grimlock.secure-dns.net';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = 'username';
        $mail->Password = 'password';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->setFrom('info@example.com', 'example');
        $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'example');
        $mail->addAddress($companyRow[1], 'example');
        $mail->WordWrap = 50;
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = "Account Detail";
        $mail->Body = $mailBody;
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
        if(!$mail->send()) {$failed++;continue;} else {$success++;continue;}
        sleep(10);
    }
    if($failed > 0) {
        $_SESSION['error'][0] = $failed . " company has error";
        $_SESSION['message'] = $success . " company has recieved mail";
    } else
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Mail Successfully Sent";
    header("location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
} else header("location:../user/out.php");
?>
```

for time interval i added sleep function but it's not working. i am testing three mails at time but all three displays same time in mailbody. please help me to add time interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line;

```
if(!$mail->send()) {$failed++;continue;} else {$success++;continue;}
```

...will do a `continue` whether the mail fails sending or not.

`continue` will skip the rest of the loop (the `sleep`) and send the next mail right away.

To execute the `sleep`, just remove `continue`;

```
if(!$mail->send()) {$failed++;} else {$success++;}
```

...or move the `sleep` before that line.

Comment: now, how can i display message at every message send or fail?